# how do i solve KeyError: 'wallets'?

Tags: python, smart-contract-wallets, brownie

I followed the answer to a similar question posted on here by adding dotenv: .env to the top of my brownie-config.yaml file but still having the same issue.

This is my code in the brownie-config.yaml file:

```
dotenv: .env

wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

This is the code from my deploy.py code:

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage, network

def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = get_account()
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)
    transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    updated_stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(updated_stored_value)


def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

This is my terminal output:

```
BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 22, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 4, in deploy_simple_storage
    account = get_account()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 18, in get_account
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
KeyError: 'wallets'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Tree:[image]

Comment: What's your tree look like? Perhaps your folders are in the wrong place.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my tree to the post.

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Your `brownie-config.yaml` is in the wrong folder. Move it down to the root folder.

In this example, move it from `tests` to `brownie_simple_storage`